# JQuery Problems with Loader Indicator and Button Disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues with Jquery. When a user clicks on the submit button, I want to replace the main contents with an animated .gif of a loader bar, and I want to disable the search button.

I have two problems:
1. The animated .gif does not move.
2. When the user presses the back button, the button is still disabled.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
  // Setup AJAX
  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });

  // Process search submit click
  var ajax_load = "<img src='static/loader.gif' />";
  var loadURL = "/results/";
  $("#search-submit").click(function() {
    $("#main").html(ajax_load).load(loadURL);
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

So, I want the animated .gif to actually move, and I want the submit button to be enabled again when the user goes back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest placing the .gif inside a div and using CSS to {display:none;}
When the submit click event is fired do this:
$('#hidden-div').show(0);
After you confirm new content is loaded use a callback function to $('#hidden-div').hide(0);

This way the animated gif is already there and should be animated.
Doing this from my phone but I hope this helped!

Comment: Hello! That worked very well. Now, do you know how to make it so the submit button is enabled again when the user hits the back button?

Comment: I'm not sure why the the submit button is not active after the page is refreshed.  You could use cookies to achieve the active and disabled state.

Comment: Hello, I managed to fix it by just disabling the 'disabled' attribute when the document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the submit button is posting the form data somewhere when its clicked.
At the same moment it is trying to redirect it is also inserting html into the #main container.
The gif may not animate because the browser is moving away from that page?

is the form submitting somewhere or is it just an iteraction with the dom?

Comment: so at the same time that the page is redirecting it is trying to load an image...  sounds to me like this is just happening too fast for you to fully download the .gif

Comment: This sounds like the problem to me, too. You might want to consider using AJAX to submit the form, keeping the main page still loaded, then the addition of the throbber (the animated GIF) on the main page would be able to be active, and you can use the success function of the AJAX call to remove the throbber and show your results from the form submission.

Comment: I am running this on my local server. I see the animated gif stay still for 3 seconds(there is a lot of processing that goes on when the submit button is pressed). Is there a way that I should do this? edit: I will try linux4me's suggestion.

Comment: Hello, I changed the Javascript so that it is using AJAX, but I still seem to have the same problem.